# Why is this summation equals $1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Referring to the conditions in parenthesis, why is the summation expression in the last line equal to $1$? (We may also assume that $-1< s < 1$.)

[image]

Comment: So you are asking why $$-\sum \frac{x^n}{n \ln(1-x)} = 1$$ for $x \in (-1,1)$?

Comment: The $\log(1-\alpha s)$ can be taken out of the summation since it doesn't depend on $n$. What's remaining is the Talor expansion of the log around 1 evaluated at $1-\alpha s$

Comment: I cannot read most of the question, some of it seems to be chopped off.

Comment: @BabyDragon Yes, it's rather crudely edited, but you can actually see all that the OP wanted you to see.

Comment: @gt6989b Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of the series expansion
$$\ln (1-x)=-\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{x^n} n$$

Comment: @RossMillikan No, because then as $x\to-1$ we would have $\ln (1-x)\to \infty$ when in fact it converges to $\ln 2$.